# nested classes in C++ don't work

Tags: c++, list, class, templates

I'm trying to build a list.
My problem comes when I'm trying to reach the field "node" inside the class "Iterator".

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class List{

  class Node;
  Node* head;
  Node* first;
  int size;

public:
   class Iterator;
   List(): head(new Node), first(new Node), size(0){};
   void insertFirst(T& element);
   void insertFirst(T element);
   int getSize();
   Iterator& begin();
};

template<class T>
class Iterator{
   friend class List<T>;
   typename List<T>::Node* node;
   List<T>* list;

 public:
   Iterator(List<T> src):node(NULL), list(&src){}
 };

 template<class T>
 typename List<T>::Iterator& List<T>::begin(){
     Iterator it(*this);
     it.node=first; <--- ***right here***
     return it;
 }
```

I'm getting "Field 'node' could not be resolved".

I have no idea what's wrong with my code.

I'll be very thankfull if somebody could help.

Comment: Try defining it as `class List<T>::Iterator { … };`.

Comment: On the line before the one you marked, try specifying the template parameter for Iterator:  `Iterator<T> it(*this);`

Answer (score 0):

The type `typename List<T>::Iterator` is declared but not defined. You defined an entirely separate type with a somewhat similar name. You probably meant to write

```
template <typename T>
class List<T>::Iterator {
    // ...
};
```